# Yup mixed não funciona notRequired ou nullable

Tags: javascript, react, yup

Boa tarde, estou validando os dados de um formulário com Yup e preciso que apenas imagens possam ser carregadas, então usei o seguinte código:

```
// formato que pode ser upado no input de email
const formatosSuportados = [
    "image/jpg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/gif",
    "image/png"
];    

// Validação das entradas
const EsquemaDeValidacao = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required('enter email'),
    corpo: Yup.string().max(500, "Too Long!").required('enter any message'),
    arquivo: Yup.mixed().nullable().test('fileFormat', 'Unsupported Format', arquivo => 
        arquivo && formatosSuportados.includes(arquivo.type)
    )
})
```

O problema é que o arquivo está sendo obrigatório para eu conseguir enviar o email. Não dispara erro algum, apenas não envia se não tem nenhum arquivo upado.

Eu já tentei com `nullable` e `notRequired`, existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa expressão sempre vai dar `falso` ***se não contiver nenhum arquivo selecionado***, então, acredito uma lógica bem básica seria testar se o arquivo não existe, retorna `true`, se ele existir retornar o outro teste, exemplo:

```
arquivo => { 
    if (!arquivo) { 
        return true;
    }
    return formatosSuportados.includes(arquivo.type) 
}
```

isso vai solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!!!